# Private Developer Roles for Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm going to be using the Facebook Open Graph API on my website to allow users to log in, upload information from their profile, and interact. I won't be publishing this app on Facebook's App Center.

My question is, is the Developer Roles section able to be private if the user navigates to the app's page? I don't want the names of the developers publicly listed. If it's not by default, is there a setting to hide that information?

I know Facebook does not want separate accounts created for the purpose of using the API, but I don't want users finding the personal accounts of those developing the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the list of admins of a Facebook app isn't displayed anywhere on Facebook or retrievable via the API unless your app is acting on behalf of one of the existing admins of that app